# get string from cursor to end of <CWORD>

Tags: vimscript, functions

In vimL, how to get a string from cursor to end of `<cWORD>`.

I know `expand('<cWORD>'`, but don't known how to keep only right part of cursor.

**Example**

given text `pre abc-xyz.xxx:123 post`,

with cursor at `-`,

return string `-xyz.xxx:123`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to take the current line, then the substring starting at the current position, split it into multiple words and take the first one. Or, in Vimscript:

```
let word = split(getline('.')[col('.')-1:])[0]
```

One alternative is to use a normal mode command such as `yW` and then access the contents of the default register (or, better, use a named register.) You can save and restore the contents of the register, so that accessing their contents after the call to the function will still return the original value.

```
function! GetWord()
    let save_reg = getreg('x')
    let save_type = getregtype('x')
    normal! "xyW
    let word = @x
    call setreg('x', save_reg, save_type)
    return word
endfunction
```

Comment: Method 1 is what I need. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Method 1.1

```
" from start of cWORD to cursor
echo matchstr(getline('.'), '\S*\%'. col('.') .'c.')
" from cursor to end of cWORD
echo matchstr(getline('.'), '\%'. col('.') .'c.\S*')
```